# Displaying unicode text on ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, unicode

I have gone through my DB and code so far, I have hit a problem. For a particular enrty in my DB I pick up descriptions and tags (both are strings)for japanese language. Now, in a ASP.NET page,the description is shown fine but the tags which are japanese as well, are replaced with ? marks, what am I doing wrong here? The same page displays description fine but within a `<div>`, tags are replaced by ? marks. The code is as follows

```
string[] tags = (Html.Encode(Item.Tags)).Split(new Char[] {',','.'});
```

in a loop over tags i have

```
<% Html.Encode(tags)%> // This is not fine!
```

While for description I have

```
<% Html.Encode(Item.Description)%> // This is fine!
```

Comment: What do you mean by the tags? Could you give an example?

Comment: tags mean text string, could be English words, or Japanese or any other language. e.g.  tags = "tokyo", "ラドクリフ"

Comment: What encodings are you using? Are you using `NVARCHAR` to properly store Unicode, assuming you're using SQL Server? Are you serving the web page as UTF-8?

Comment: I am using SQL server, with nvarchar as data type for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be problem in the stored procedure.
the variable storing the strings and returning them to ASP.NET had to be a nvarchar and rather was a varchar.  Fixed my problem in ASP.NET eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Are you encoding them twice? `Html.Encode(Item.Tags)` and then `Html.Encode(tags)`

Comment: Ok, i removed the second Html.encode (tags). Still not working

Comment: Is the description and tags stored the same way in the database (same data type)?

Comment: Yup, I just checked again after reading your question. They appear fine as Japanese text.